# Failed request tracing truncated buffer

Tags: iis, trace

I am debugging my website, and I decided to enable `Failed request tracing`. Everything works fine, but when I open the XML log file almost every `GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER` ends with `TRUNCATED`. So the response is not complete in the log file, and I need to see the complete response.

I tried to set `maxLogFileSizeKb` to `2048`. But I got still `TRUNCATED` data in `GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER`.

What do I need to do to get the whole response?

Comment: please let me know if anyone found the solution not to be truncated. thanks